# What use is macro expansion on an "#include" line?

Tags: include, c-preprocessor

Is there any practical use for macro expansion on an "#include" line?

For example, a header file like

```
// calculated_include.h
#define THE_STRING "Hello, World!\n"
```

Then a C or C++ file like

```
// calculated_include.c
#define HEADER_MACRO "calculated_include.h"
#define STDIO <stdio.h>

#include STDIO
#include HEADER_MACRO

int main(void){
        printf("%s", THE_STRING );
}
```

Then from the command line I do

```
make calculated_include
./calculated_include
```

and it prints out, as you've probably already guessed,

> Hello, World!

I see some people call macro expansion on an "#include" line ["calculated includes"](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Talk:C_Programming/Preprocessor#Calculated_Includes_and_X-Macros) or ["computed includes"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Computed-Includes.html#Computed-Includes); is there a better name?

I see that one person wanted to use text substitution in a "#include" file so a filename specified on the gcc command line with the "-D" option would get substituted into an "#include" statement (
[How can I specify an include file from the GCC Command Line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537450/how-can-i-specify-an-include-file-from-the-gcc-command-line) ).
But it seems to me that specifying that filename directly with the "-include" command-line option instead ( [Include header files using command line option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387453/include-header-files-from-command-line-gcc) and ["Options Controlling the Preprocessor"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)) would be simpler and work just as well.

Is there any other use for macro expansion on an "#include" line?

Comment: You could use it to include header files for another architecture (different CPU or platform) or for specifying a build variant (e.g. Debug or Release). Your macro would then define the path to look for the include files. Obviously, there are other ways of achieving this.

Comment: I think you mean the `-include` option, but anyway that is gcc-specific, and other compilers might not have an analogous option. On the other hand, pretty well every compiler has an equivalent to `-D`.

Comment: @rici: Thank you, the "-include" option is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

one use case is that, it helps you to select one of several different header files to be included into your program.  [check this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Computed-Includes.html)

Comment: I feel that you didn't actually read the question, because I already mentioned that "use case" and that link in the last 4 sentences of the question.